# Wrong mesh deformation when I did "assign automatic from bones"

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones

I'm rigging the eyes of my character following [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCGekumdLLU).

I've reached 16:34 of the video, when he selects "assign automatic from bones" to the eyebrow bones. I did the same, but in my case the mesh of the left eye deformed incorrectly. I tried changing the bone's influence with the weight paint, but I made a mess. I've attached two pics to show what happened.

[image: mesh eye incorrectly deformed]

[image: mesh eye configured correctly]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you using the same model in the Tutorial?

Comment: No. He does not want to give the model to anyone. I created a bird starting from another tutorial and then I modified it. Can you give a look ? get it here : http://psychonews.it/dati/Pierino93.blend ; very thanks.

Comment: The reason I asked, is that assigning weighs automatically only work for simple straight forward meshes, if you have some complicated mesh or loose vertices, it's well expected for it not to work, it's always better to paint them or assign them manually.

Comment: I tried to use the weight painting but i havent been able to deform correctly the mesh. Can you make a short video to show me how to do ? You can use the same model that im working with.

Comment: The tutorial in this link is explaining the way to do it very well, specially after minute 7, I hope this helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3gIN4dJYw4